# How to invoke onclick event inside div tag child element

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

Need to invoke onclick method from child element of div tag which has no ID or name . in my website there are lot of div tags. I want to traverse to particular div tag which has class name and gets its child element a tag which also does have id and invoke onclick method contained in it.
HTML :

New incident

I used web browser controls in c# but could not able to access that a tag and invoke the method since lot of div tags are there. 
PS No htmlagilitypack. Its a secure environment I can't download those pack.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use HtmlAgilityPack, you could use C# XPath API. It functions the same exact way. That would probably be the easiest method besides Regex.

Answer (score 0):

If child element 'does have id' then this id should be unique within HTML document and then 'clicking' on that child element by C# code could be implemented as the following:

```
        var doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        string childTagId = "{{type your child tag id here}}";

        doc.GetElementById(childTagId).InvokeMember("click");
```

But if child tag's id isn't unique within HTML document and DIV's class name is unique (assumption based on your description) then C# code would become:

```
        var doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        string childTagId = "{{type your child tag id here}}";
        string className = "{{type your test className here}}";
        string childTagName = "{{type your child tag name here}}";

        doc.GetElementsByTagName("div").OfType<System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement>()
                 .Where(x => x.GetAttribute("className") == className).First()
                 .All.OfType<System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement>()
                 .Where(x => string.Compare(x.TagName, childTagName, true) == 0 &&
                             x.GetAttribute("id") == childTagId)
                 .First()
                 .InvokeMember("click");
```